# Expose method as a property in user control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I created user control for textbox with autocompleteextender, and its working fine, but now i wanted to expose methods in user control to aspx page as a one of the property in user control,like in button control having onClientClick event.
and forgive my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a property like this to your user control:

```
public string OnClientClick
{
    get { return Button1.OnClientClick; }
    set
    {
        Button1.OnClientClick = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: i had one more problem i,e if i expose this event as a property means I'm not getting set property of SelectedValue because previously i set hidden field value in onClientItemSelect event of autocompleteextender which is in UserControl and exposed this value in SelectedValue property, so how can i set this property?. any solution means ll be appreciated

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you'd just want to create another property to get and set the 'SelectedValue', just like in the example above.